# Porting POSIX Socket Application to Winsocket2. Only Works when debug messages are activated

Tags: c, visual-studio, sockets, debugging

I am porting this MQTT Client (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c) from Posix to Windows. 
I stumbled upon this very weired problem, where I get a connection to my Broker, when I have debug message turned on in Visual Studio, but the connection fails if the Debug message is off. 
I use the Visual Studio breakpoints, which dont stop the programm, but print a message into the debug console.

I was thinking that it might be a timing problem (like the Windows socket was not ready or something like that), and the debug message costs some extra time in which the initialisation might be completed. So I tried to replace the Debug message with a while loop counting a variable up, or with some printf statements. Both didn't work.

```
static int readPacket(MQTTClient* c, Timer* timer)
{

    MQTTHeader header = {0};
    int len = 0;
    int rem_len = 0;

// <--- Here is where I need the VS debug print Breakpoint

    /* 1. read the header byte.  This has the packet type in it */
    int rc = c->ipstack->mqttread(c->ipstack, c->readbuf, 1, TimerLeftMS(timer));
    if (rc != 1)
        goto exit;

    len = 1;
    /* 2. read the remaining length.  This is variable in itself */
    decodePacket(c, &rem_len, TimerLeftMS(timer));
...
...
...
}
```

The debug log needs to happen before the mqttread function is called. In that function the socket recv function is called.

I havbe no Idea how to debug this, since the process of debugging changes the course of the programm. I feel like a quantum physicist, where I can not observe something without influencing the thing I am observing...

Any recommendations how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) are often caused by memory problems which happen to be top problems in C. Add some `printf()` here and there to check all your allocations and array accesses.

Comment: Code compiled into a debug executable behaves different in several ways, most commonly observed difference being slower execution time, but other effects almost certainly exist as well.  There is merit in what @thebusybee suggests.  I would take it a step further.  Place printf statements liberally through the code in the spots of interest to view the results of _all_ of your non-void function calls.  Then run it in a normal executable, i.e. _not_ debug.  This will remove all of the effects of the highly modified debug version.

Comment: @ryyker You're perfectly right. Just a note, because I fell into that trap, too: The OP did not write about a difference between debug and non-debug run, but about a difference between with and without a breakpoint and its message.

Comment: Correct, I only used the debug mode of VS yet. I also can have Debug print breakpoints in differnet parts of the code, which do not affect the behavior, and then there is this one spot where the breakpoint makes a difference. I narrowed it down that the breakpoint must happen before the recv function called, however I still cant figure out what causes the problem.